# swiftc failed with error code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i am building a swift/objc app. I have the app working fine on the device, but when i try to archive i get an error

> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1

The error seems to link to my Bridging-Header.h file.

I've tried some solutions with no success:

- cleaning the Derived Data
- setting the optimization level to None

**UPDATE**

i've installed xcode 6.3 beta 2 and upgraded class with appropriate swift 1.2; in the editor, the build works fine, but when i try to build in the terminal using:

```
xcodebuild -project Proj.xcodeproj
```

and i do get a specific error:

> Call parameter type does not match function signature!
>   %V4Hive15MultivalueEntry.64* %0
>    %V4Hive15MultivalueEntry*  tail call void @_TFFC4Hive22SwiftAddressBookPersonP33_FEAC8E239DA88BD1517B50EB72890C1824convertMultivalueEntriesFS0_U_Ss9AnyObject__FTGSqGSaGVS_15MultivalueEntryQ____9converterFQ_Q0__GSqGSaGS2_Q0____U_FGS2_Q__GS2_Q0__(%V4Hive15MultivalueEntry.64* noalias sret %0, %V4Hive15MultivalueEntry.63* noalias %3, i8* %.fn.load, %swift.refcounted* %6, %swift.type* getelementptr inbounds (%swift.full_type* @_TMdSS, i32 0, i32 1), %swift.type* %7), !dbg !5089
>   LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
>   2015-03-05 10:08:02.467 xcodebuild[6416:24559]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-7523/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/BuildCommandResultsPostprocessing/XCClangResultsPostprocessor.m:68
>   Details:  Unable to read diagnostics from file "/Users/erpk/Documents/Work/Hive/Hive/build/Hive.build/Release-iphoneos/Hive.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AddressBookManager.dia" (Invalid File): Invalid diagnostics signature
>   Function: void XCGenerateDiagnosticsFromFile(NSString *__strong, NSString *__strong, NSDictionary *__strong, NSDictionary *__strong, IDEActivityLogSectionRecorder *__strong, BOOL (^__strong)(IDEActivityLogMessage *__strong))
>   Thread:   {number = 7, name = (null)}
>   Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

the main thing to get from this is

```
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
```

this is generated in a certain file:

http://snipsave.com/user/profile/badescualex#10418

Answer (score 0):

It looks like he problem is that there is an internal compiler error in the file AddressBookManager.swift  I would start commenting out all implementation until you can get it to pass the build.  Binary search style.  You should be able to isolate it better that way.  It would be great if you could provide the Swift team a failing project.  They are generally very responsive given a repeatable test case.